# What does $\dot{-}$ means

Tags: notation, ordinals

I was reading [Accesible Independence Results for Peano Arithmetic, Kirby & Paris](https://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lkirby/accessible_independence_results.pdf) and saw a symbol (at top of the $\mbox{page 288}$, in $\mbox{Lemma 3.}$) like $\dot{-}$ which I do not know what it means.

It appearing like this:

$\dots$ then $o_{n+1}\left(m\dot{-}1\right)=\langle\alpha\rangle\left(n\right)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [Monus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monus#Natural_numbers): $a ∸ b=0$ when $a < b$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!